# post data on is viewed on expired page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I log in to the site and navigate to one page X where I post data and then I log out. It takes to log out page and after that if I click back button it takes me back to page X but shows message page is expired I try to resend same page or click refresh and resubmit same page.. I have fiddler running and now I see the data is posted ... I was able to see this in proxy tool fiddler.
Now due to security issue when I try to resubmit expired page I don't want to see my form data in fiddler.
How do I do this.
I already tried all the on page load event for above page X. Page x is user control.

```
  Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-cache");
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Expires = -1; case"

        Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);

        Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();

        Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent this behavior (other than trying to clear the browser history which is not simple). This is a function of the browser / client. It will try to re-post the data, which is normal. Your system should handle it accordingly by ignoring the data if the user isn't authenticated or logged in.

Comment: My system handles it accordingly no issues. But security people are failing my code because they are able to see same data in proxy tool.

Comment: Those security people might not be super familiar with browsers then, because they all behave this way.

Comment: so there is no way I can avoid showing this data in proxy tool?

Comment: Not reliably, no.

Comment: so user just logs out and leaves the browser open, sensitive info from form post will be always available thru proxy tool even if cache settings are set up as mentioned above on form post page? What options do I have to get rid of this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Having the user close the browser window on session end.